# find combination pairs of attribute variables

Tags: r, combinations

I looked around for a solution but could not find an exact one.

Given:

```
a<-c('a','b','c')
b<-c('d','e','f')
d<-c('g','h')
```

as a toy subset of a much larger set, I want to be able to find unique pairs between
attribute (vector) sets.  If I use

```
combn(c(a,b,d),2)
```

It would return ALL pairwise combinations of all of the attribute elements. 
e.g.

```
combn(c(a,b,d),2)
```

returns  c(a,b)  c(a,d) c(a,d) c(a,e)...

But I only want pairs of elements between attributes. So I would not see a,b or a,c but
a,d a,e a,f b,d b,e,b,f etc...

I could sort of do it with expand.grid(a,b,d)..

```
   Var1 Var2 Var3
1     a    d    g
2     b    d    g
3     c    d    g
4     a    e    g
5     b    e    g
6     c    e    g
7     a    f    g
8     b    f    g
9     c    f    g
10    a    d    h
11    b    d    h
12    c    d    h
13    a    e    h
14    b    e    h
15    c    e    h
16    a    f    h
17    b    f    h
18    c    f    h
```

but now I have an n-col dimensional set of the combinations. Is there any way to limit
it to just attribute pairs of elements, such as combn(x,2)

The main goal is to find a list of unique pairwise combinations of elements between all attribute pairs, but I do not want combinations of elements 
within the same attribute column, as it is redundant in my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking combinations of pairs in each row in the grid, then filtering to get unique entries, we have this:

```
unique(do.call(c, apply(expand.grid(a,b,d), 1, combn, m=2, simplify=FALSE)))
```

A list of combinations is returned:

```
> L <- unique(do.call(c, apply(expand.grid(a,b,d), 1, combn, m=2, simplify=FALSE)))[1:5]
> length(L) ## 21
> L
## [[1]]
## Var1 Var2 
##  "a"  "d" 
## 
## [[2]]
## Var1 Var3 
##  "a"  "g" 
## 
## [[3]]
## Var2 Var3 
##  "d"  "g" 
## 
## [[4]]
## Var1 Var2 
##  "b"  "d" 
## 
## [[5]]
## Var1 Var3 
##  "b"  "g"
```

Comment: For some reason I'm getting: Error in do.call(c, apply(expand.grid(a, b, d), 1, combn, m = 2, simplify = FALSE)) : 
  'what' must be a character string or a function .... my variables are all class(character) and I'm using Revolution R 64 bit. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a variable named `c`?  I removed that for my example (and edited your question to remove it there).

Comment: I set it to null and renamed (old) c to d.

Comment: Set to NULL still exists.  `rm(c)`.

Comment: whoops. I just realized it repeats combinations. If anyone wants unique only, I just use unique(f), where f is the returned list.

Comment: You are correct.  Because for example, c('a', 'd') is a pair contained in c('a', 'd', 'g') and c('a', 'd', 'h').  I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, create a list where each element is a pair of your original vectors, e.g. `list(a, b)`:

```
L <- list(a, b, d)
L.pairs <- combn(seq_along(L), 2, simplify = FALSE, FUN = function(i)L[i])
```

Then run `expand.grid` for each of these pairs and put the pieces together:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(L.pairs, expand.grid))
#    Var1 Var2
# 1     a    d
# 2     b    d
# 3     c    d
# [...]
# 19    d    h
# 20    e    h
# 21    f    h
```

Comment: It's an application of Fubini away from my answer.  I like it.

Comment: Fubini, Fubini... My version is not creating duplicates :-)